# split/reference big file by offset reference

Tags: linux, filesystems

[`split`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) splits a file into pieces which in total consumes the same storage space (doubling the consumed disk space).

[`ln`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ln) can create a symbolic link (symlink) to other (target) file while not duplicating the file and thus does not consume double the space of the target file.

due to the lack of storage space, can a file be split by reference/symbolicly (i.e. virtually splitting the file) that points to specific offsets in the big file?

for example, given a file which is 2MB break it to 2 pieces, where each piece reference 1mb of the big file (in the same concept that symlink works), such that each piece:

- does not overlap other pieces (pieces will not reference the same data in the big file)
- does not consume the same storage size as the big file portion it references

```
piece_1.file -> 2mb.file 1st MB
piece_2.file -> 2mb.file 2nd MB
```

and the storage size of each piece is much less than 1MB

Comment: Is your intention really to exclude a single bit? bit addressing isn't possible (in general), and I think you mean "1 MB from the 0. byte" and "1 MB from after the 1. MB", right?

Comment: @MarcusMüller correct. was just giving an example. depends if the reference is inclusive or not. in general, i just want to split without duplicating the target size and without any aliasing (referencing the same location, not to read the data twice)

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying in that comment. Could you please **edit** your question and explain what you want to achieve in general, instead of here in special? I'm writing an answer, and I think your general question might **fundamentally** change what I should be writing. (and remove the +1bit? that is really a very hefty complication of your situation and essentially would need a completely different approach which involves mounting some rather complicated and slow file system layer that you would have to code yourself.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller edited. i hope it is clearer now :)

Comment: Hard links are just distinct names to a single file, with the file itself being "whole". For them to to work, the inode (which is basically the structure describing the file), needs to keep a reference count, so the system knows when the last name is gone and can delete the file. Regular filesystems don't have that on the block level.

Comment: Though  _technically_, if you're mad enough, you could mess with the filesystem internals so that you have multiple files that point at the same blocks. It'd likely break down horribly if one of the files was deleted or truncated. Some advanced filesystems have such features, though, e.g. Btrfs has reflinks, which are basically files that share data blocks, in a controlled manner. The docs say they could in principle be used for partial ranges too. https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Reflink.html Fixing something up with FUSE would also be possible (non-answer, since not really a solution.)

Comment: @ilkkachu well, it works pretty well at least on XFS (and seeing that offers the same `map_file_range` methodology in the VFS, it should work just the same with btrfs) when you `copy_file_range`. Added a demo to the end of my post to show that!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, right, I meant I didn't have anything concrete, not that it wouldn't be possible to work a useful solution from that. :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> due to the lack of storage space, can a file be split by reference/symbolicly (i.e. virtually splitting the file) that points to specific offsets in the big file?

Not directly, no. Files don't work that way in the thinking of POSIX. They're more independent, atomic units of data.

Two options:

## Loopback devices

This is a *runtime* solution, meaning that it's not an on-disk solution, but needs to be set up manually. That might be an advantage or a disadvantage!

You can set up a loopback device quite easily; if you're using a freedesktop system message bus-compatible session manager (i.e., you're logged in to your machine graphically and are running gnome, xfce4, kde,…), udisks is your friend:

```bash
blksize=$((2**20))
udisksctl loop-setup -s $blksize -f /your/large/file
udisksctl loop-setup -s $blksize -o $blksize -f /your/large/file
```

- The first command gives you a `/dev/loop` which starts at the 0. byte and goes on for 2²⁰ bytes (i.e., a megabyte).
- The second  command gives you a `/dev/loop+` which starts at the 2²⁰. byte and goes on for 2²⁰ bytes (i.e., a megabyte). (Note how we're starting to count at 0, so that this is actually *exactly after* the first chunk.)

You can then use these two loopback devices, e.g. `/dev/loop0` and `/dev/loop1`. They literally describe a "view" into your file. You change something in these block devices, you change it in your large file.

If you're not logging in graphically, the exact same can be achieved, but you need root privileges:

```bash
blksize=$((2**20))
sudo losetup --sizelimit $blksize -f /your/large/file
sudo losetup --sizelimit $blksize -o $blksize -f /your/large/file
```

## Reflinking the storage blocks

This is an on-disk solution. It will also make a "logical" copy, i.e., if you change something in your small files, it will *not* be reflected in the large file.

You **must** use a file system that supports `reflink` (to the [best of my knowledge](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631237/in-linux-which-filesystems-support-reflinks), these are XFS, Btrfs and some network file systems). (File system blocks through which a split goes would need to be duplicated, but for most filesystems, we're talking less than 4 kB here.)

In that case, your file system can *copy files without the copy using any space of its own*, as long as the copy or original aren't changed (and even if they are, only the affected parts are duplicated).

So, on such a file system, we have two options:

1. make the split into the first and the second half "normally", and then ask a utility (`duperemove`) to compare the three files and deduplicate.
2. make the copy of the two halves of your file in a manner that hints the file system to directly avoid using twice the space.

Since the first option temporarily needs twice the space, let's do the second right away. I wrote a small program to do that split for you ([full source code](https://gist.github.com/marcusmueller/d1e0235f9a484cb44626e35460a5c0ac)) (**Attention: Found a bug, which I'm not going to fix. This is just an example**). The relevant excerpt is this:

```c
// this is file mysplit.c , a C99 program
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Linux-man-pages-copyleft
// (heavily based on the copy_file_range(2) man page example)
// compile with `cc -o mysplit mysplit.c`
// […]
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
[…]
        ret = copy_file_range(fd_in /*input file descriptor*/,
                              &in_offset /*address of input offset*/,
                              fd_out /*output file descriptor*/,
                              NULL /*address of output offset*/,
                              len /*amount of bytes to copy*/,
                              0 /*flags (reserved, must be ==0)*/);
[…]
}
```

Let's try that out. We'll have to:

- get and compile my program
- make a XFS file system first, as that's one of the file systems that supports reflinks
- mount it
- put a large file filled with random data inside
- check the free space on that file system
- add splits of the file (using my program)
- check the free space again.

The script below does just that.

```bash
# replace "apt" with "dnf" if you're on some kind of redhat/fedora
# replace "apt install" with "pacman" followed by a randomly guessed amount of options involving the letters {y, s, S, u} if you're on arch or manjaro
apt install curl gcc xfsprogs

# Download the C program from above
curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/marcusmueller/d1e0235f9a484cb44626e35460a5c0ac/raw/6295f9f6371b916b87a5d0a5a6edad65f9ea8627/mysplit.c > mysplit.c

# Comile
cc -o mysplit mysplit.c

# Demo:  (doesn't need root privileges if you got udisks)
# Make file system in a file system image,
# Mount that image
# create a 300 MB file in there,
# split it,
# show there's still nearly the same amount of free space


# Make file system in a file system image
fallocate -l 1G filesystemimage # 1 GB in size
## this is a bit confusing, but to make the root of the file system
## world-writable, we do:
echo "thislinejustforbackwardscompatibility/samefornextline
1337 42
d--777 ${UID} ${GID}" > /tmp/protofile
mkfs.xfs -p /tmp/protofile -L testfs filesystemimage

# Mount that image
loopdev=$(LANG=C udisksctl loop-setup -f filesystemimage | sed 's/.* as \(.*\).$/\1/')
## on most systems, that new device is automatically mounted.
sleep 3
## udisksctl mount -b "${loopdev}"

# create a 300 MB file in there,
target="/run/media/$(whoami)/testfs"
rndfile="${target}/largefile"
dd if=/dev/urandom "of=${rndfile}" bs=1M count=300
## Check free space
echo "free space with large file"
df -h "${target}"

# split it,
## (copy the first 100 MB)
./mysplit "${rndfile}" "${target}/split_1" 0 $((2**20 * 100))
## (copy the next 120 MB, just showing off that splits don't need to be of uniform size)
./mysplit "${rndfile}" "${target}/split_2" "$((2**20 * 100))" "$((2**20 * 120))"
# show there's still nearly the same amount of free space
## Check free space
echo "free space with large file + splits"
df -h "${target}"
```

Comment: An addition to the reflink approach is that ZFS and BTRFS allow block-level deduplication. While a reflink file on ext4 is copied once you change it, BTRFS will only copy the changed blocks. To deduplicate existing blocks one can just `jdupes -B`.

Comment: @allo didn't even know ext4 had file-level reflinking at all!

Comment: I think it did not have it in its first revisions, but now it has had it long enough that one can assume that most systems support it.

Comment: apparently, there is a limitation on the amount of loopback devices that can be created :(

Comment: @Mr. I don't think that's true, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554438/what-is-maximum-loop-devices-for-linux-kernel

Answer (score 7):

On Linux, it's the kind of thing  you can  do with `loop` devices.

For instance:

```
losetup --find --show             --sizelimit=2M file
losetup --find --show --offset=2M --sizelimit=2M file
losetup --find --show --offset=4M --sizelimit=2M file
```

Would output the  paths of 3 loop devices that reference 3 2MiB large sections of the `file`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize `losetup` supported `M` as offset (man page does mention it, though).

Answer (score -2):

If I understood your right this comes close to your question. Isn't it?

```
supu@devuan ~/TEST ❖ cat bigfile.txt                                                               8:01
DIES IST VIEL TEXT
DIES IST VIEL TEXT

supu@devuan ~/TEST ❖ split -n2 bigfile.txt

supu@devuan ~/TEST ❖ ls -l                                                                         8:00
insgesamt 12.288
-rw-r--r-- 1 supu supu 38 2023-03-14 07:59 bigfile.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 supu supu  3 2023-03-14 08:00 piece1 -> xaa
lrwxrwxrwx 1 supu supu  3 2023-03-14 08:00 piece2 -> xab
-rw-r--r-- 1 supu supu 19 2023-03-14 08:00 xaa
-rw-r--r-- 1 supu supu 19 2023-03-14 08:00 xab
supu@devuan ~/TEST ❖ cat piece?                                                                    8:00
DIES IST VIEL TEXT
DIES IST VIEL TEXT
supu@devuan ~/TEST ❖ cat xa?                                                                       8:01
DIES IST VIEL TEXT
DIES IST VIEL TEXT
supu@devuan ~/TEST ❖
```

Comment: i would like to avoid the duplication of the big file data. seems like total size of `xaa` and `xab` (combined) as the same size as `bigfile.txt`