# How can I copy arbitrary part of binary file with reasonable speed?

Tags: dd

How can I copy arbitrary part of a binary file with reasonable speed?

Apparently, `dd` with `bs=1` is very slow, while setting `bs` to another value makes it impossible to copy arbitrary parts.

Is it wrong? Is it possible to do with `dd`? If not, then what is the tool?

For example, this command,

```
dd if="$img" of=tail.bin bs=2147483648 skip=1 status=progress
```

copies an incorrect tail.

And this command,

```
dd if="$img" of=tail.bin bs=1 skip=2147483648 status=progress
```

is very slow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read the middle of a large file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121794/read-the-middle-of-a-large-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [split/reference big file by offset reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/739665/split-reference-big-file-by-offset-reference)

Comment: I have an example program in my answer to that question that does what you want - you specify an input and an output file as well as an offset into the input file and a length and it just goes off and copies that part with as few context switches as possible, leaving optimal transfer sizes up to the kernel

Comment: Incorrect tail?  GNU `strace dd if=file of=/tmp/tail.bin bs=2147483648 skip=1` appears to do the right thing, first `lseek(0, 2147483648, SEEK_CUR)` on the input, then `read(0, "\205..."..., 2147483648) = 2147479552` and `write(1, buf, read_size)`, then another `read(0, buf, 2147483648)` gets to the end of the file, returning much shorter instead of slightly shorter.  After printing a partial-read warning, it writes out that partial block, then read(0, buf, bs) returns 0.  So it ends and prints `"0+2 records in\n0+2 records out\n"`.

Comment: So it works for me, unless the offset is a prime number larger than the amount of memory it can use for a buffer for the rest of the file.  GNU dd's `skip_bytes` is of course even better.  Or for the whole tail, `tail -c +offset`.  But if you want to write to the middle of a file with `conv=notrunc`, you want `dd`.

Comment: `cmp --ignore-initial=2147483648:0 src tail.bin` confirms `tail.bin` is identical.  Oh, but apparently if `dd` is interrupted during a `read` system call, it can lose data?

Comment: @PeterCordes, if it reads a partial block, it should write a partial block, so the resulting byte stream should be the same. That's not the case if 1) you use `count=N`, since it limits the total number of input blocks it reads, counting partial ones; or 2) you use `conv=sync`, when it fills the partial blocks with NULs; or 3) the device you write is blocksize sensitive (where I suppose `sync` could help in some cases). But having to think any of this should work as evidence that `dd` usually isn't the right tool for generic byte-stream copying :)

Comment: @ilkkachu: Ah, that makes sense.  I was only testing with the command in the question, which copies the whole tail, not a fixed-length chunk from the middle.  That would indeed have failed since `bs` was so large I got a short read.

Comment: How about spinning up nginx and curl-ing the necessary part from localhost with a `Range` header? ;-)

Answer (score 21):

GNU dd supports `count_bytes`, `seek_bytes`, `skip_bytes` flags. This allows you to use a performant blocksize choice with arbitrary offsets and sizes.

GNU dd since version 9.1 does this by default if you specify a byte unit.

Quoting from [coreutils/NEWS](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/6272817de007d236f82616df5916be37333ba163/NEWS#L263-L267):

> dd now counts bytes instead of blocks if a block count ends in "B".
> For example, 'dd count=100KiB' now copies 100 KiB of data, not
> 102,400 blocks of data.  The flags count_bytes, skip_bytes and
> seek_bytes are therefore obsolescent and are no longer documented,
> though they still work.

Another option is to create a loop device with the desired offset and size limits. That works for dd (or any other program) that does not support arbitrary offsets by itself.

Alternatively you could also consider copying only the partial first/last block with bs=1 and the middle segment with your desired larger blocksize.

Comment: The last paragraph, while a working suggestion, is unnecessarily complex to code.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
tail -c +$FROM file.dat | head -c $LENGTH > file1.dat
```

Just assign FROM and LENGTH as you need. Note that the numbering for `tail` is one-based and e.g. `tail -c +4` means to start at the fourth byte, that is to skip the first three bytes.

As an example:

```
$ printf 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n' > test.txt
$ tail -c +4 test.txt | head -c 6; echo
defghi
```

Comment: Are parameters here zero based and TO exclusive and FROM inclusive?

Comment: @Dims reading `man head` and `man tail` you can see that `head -c 5` would give you the first five bytes of the source, and piping to `tail -c +3` (or indeed `head -c 3`) would give you the first three bytes of that

Comment: @roaima You got it wrong with the tail. `use -c +NUM to output starting with byte NUM`. It will give you the last characters, starting with 3.

Comment: If `$FROM` can be large, it's _probably_ more efficient to do `tail -c +$FROM file.dat | head -c $LENGTH`. That way `tail` can seek past the first `$FROM` bytes and start reading from there (and stop when it gets a SIGPIPE after `head` stops reading more data).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, yes, that's a good point. At least GNU tail does seek (no surprise), Busybox didn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole tail of the file starting from some position, one way would be to seek a file descriptor to the correct position and just copy with `cat`. Relatively simple to do with Perl and a shell redirection:

```
$ printf 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n' > test.txt
$ { perl -e 'sysseek STDIN, 23, 0'; cat; } < test.txt
xyz
```

or with the count passed through the environment instead to not mix it up with the code:

```
$ { N=23 perl -e 'sysseek STDIN, $ENV{N}, 0'; cat; } < test.txt
xyz
```

A subshell `(perl; cat)` works too. Note that this is *not* a pipeline, just `perl` and `cat` using the same open file description. Though note the lack of error checking above, if the seek fails, it'll just not happen.

To copy a set number of bytes only, pipe to `head -c` instead of `cat`:

```
$ start=3 count=6
$ { N=$start perl -e 'sysseek STDIN, $ENV{N}, 0'; head -c $count; } < test.txt; echo
defghi
```